# Unable to login to Pokemon go off Wi-fi

Tags: pokemon-go

I have an iPhone 6+ running the newest 10.0.2 update. I am logging in with the PTC and not with google. I have been playing the game since Mid-July with absolutely no issues. Starting after the newest iPhone update the game would randomly crash on me during game play a lot. Battling a gym, catching a pokemon, at pokestops it didn't matter just crash and I would re-start with no issues. Until this past week I started having issues logging in, the load bar would get about 10% then sign out would pop up and it would say "failed to login". Sometimes it would randomly work and I could play but mostly it didn't. I started logging in on wifi at home then leaving the house and could play for a while unless it crashed and then it would go back to failed to login in. And now three days ago, I can log-in from home on wi-fi and play but as soon as I leave wi-fi although the game is still on if I click on a pokemon I get "error", if I click on a gym I get "network error". So I can no longer play at all unless I am connected to wi-fi.

Now before you mark this as a duplicate, I would like to point out I have an iPhone and the android fixes from other questions will NOT help me.

I have been researching this all day and cannot seem to find anyone with an iPhone that is having the same issue and it has been resolved. Seems plenty of people have this issue but I have yet to see a fix for the iPhone.

So anyone else have this problem and find a way to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: Whats your network carrier? Google accounts have been down via cricket wireless since 9/30

Comment: I actually am on cricket but I login via the Pokemon Trainer Account does that make a difference?

Comment: I haven't tested it - I don't have a PTC account

Answer (score 1):

If you are on cricket wireless:

Go to any ip address checking website, and make sure your IP begins with 216.xxx.xxx.xxx. Niantic has been banning other cricket IPs due to excessive botting/spoofing/spamming from other cricket IP addresses, but the 216.xxx ones appear to be ok.

To change your IP address on your phone, turn your phone onto airplane mode (or otherwise disable mobile data) for ~10 seconds, turn it back on, and check again.